# How to use a swing timer to wait 1 second before continuing to execute code?

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay

I literally just want to do the following:

```
System.out.println("First line");
// wait 1 second
button.setText("newText");
```

I tried using thread sleep but it doesn't work. I'm trying to understand swing timers but its so needlessly confusing. I just want the code to delay a second.

Further clarification:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
clicked.setText("you clicked this button");
//timer here for 1 second,like a delay
clicked.setText("");
```

Comment: does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: A Swing `Timer` uses a `ActionListener` as callback/observer which is notified when the timer ticks.  Use the `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed` method to update the state of the UI

Comment: The problem is that i need this timer to execute which is already in the actionListener's code,at a specific spot

Comment: When a button is clicked,a bunch of stuff happens, then the timer should wait 1 second, then update the text of the button.

Comment: *The problem is that i need this timer to execute which is already in the actionListener's code* - and that is your design problem. The code in your ActionListener needs to be split into two. You execute the code up to the first "setText()" statement. Then you start the Timer. When the Timer executes, you invoke the remaining code. So you need the code broken up into two ActionListeners. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem if you need more help.

Comment: First, the problem with your void situation is that your probably tried to assign the Timer instance to a variable `timer` which is not what I did.  The `start()` returns void which was the problem.  But based on your edits. you have a fundamental problem.  You can not run two processes currently in the EDT.  So while you are in the `actionPerformed` method, you won't receive the event from the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.  The first argument is the initial delay of 1000 ms.  Then the `ActionEvent` object is used to get the creator of the event (the timer) and stop it.

```
System.out.println("First line");
new Timer(1000, (ae)->{
               button.setText("newText"); 
               ((Timer)ae.getSource()).stop();
}).start();
```

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch: cannot convert from void to timer

Comment: I can't explain it it works for me just fine.  First check your syntax.  Then if that is correct can you edit your question and show the context of how you are using it?  And make certain you don't assign the Timer to anything.  It runs standalone.  That is don't do this `Timer timer =  new Timer(....`